# Why is radicale server crashing with `Host is down`-message?

Tags: debian, radicale

My radicale server was crashing with the following log messages from `journalctl`

```
Jan 02 04:28:13 RPi64 systemd[1]: Started A simple CalDAV (calendar) and CardDAV (contact) server.
Jan 02 04:28:23 RPi64 systemd[14181]: radicale.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/: Host is down
Jan 02 04:28:23 RPi64 systemd[14181]: radicale.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /usr/bin/env: Host is down
Jan 02 04:28:23 RPi64 systemd[1]: radicale.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
Jan 02 04:28:23 RPi64 systemd[1]: radicale.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 02 04:29:24 RPi64 systemd[1]: radicale.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 8.
Jan 02 04:29:24 RPi64 systemd[1]: Stopped A simple CalDAV (calendar) and CardDAV (contact) server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to a missing host which should have been loaded from `/etc/fstab`. Since the log provides no (obvious) connection to the problem and I did not find a good solution online I decided to put it here.

```
//192.168.1.18/MOUNTPOINT         /mnt/MOUNTPOINT             cifs ro,auto,nofail,users,credentials=/root/credentials.MOUNTPOINT,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

Once I removed `auto` from the line in `/etc/fstab` the problem was solved.